# Can I load a component dynamically into a mat-drawer component?

Tags: angular

I have a mat-drawer on my main component and I would like to use that for my modals.  I'm not sure that I can do that.  This is what I have:

```
<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet></mat-drawer-content>
    <mat-drawer mode="side" position="end" (openChange)-"...' (closed)="...">

    </mat-drawer>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

What I'd like to do is take this following:

```
showDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(myComponent, {
    data:{},
    disableClose: false });
}
```

and somehow add "myComponent" to the mat-drawer.

Can't say that I've seen a lot of examples of how to do this.  Any ideas on what I should be looking for?

As I continue to search maybe the Portals will work for what I'm trying to do. https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview

I'm still searching, so any suggestions would be very helpful.